# In Excel, is it possible to automate reading of CSV data into a template and printing it to PDF from the commandline?

Tags: excel, pdf, command-line, automation

Current process conception is:

1. **DATA GENERATION:** Data is generated via a standard process; meaning that though the values change, the location of the data is stored in the same location (cell A1's value will change, but the "label/mapping" of that data is static, or not changing.)
2. **DATA STORED:** Data written to a single file location in delimited form (CSV,Tab, etc.) or to a MySQL database; meaning data is written and processed in serial, not in parallel; meaning a new job/task is not started until the current one is done; if it's possible to do in parallel that's fine, but it's not a requirement.
3. **DATA LOADED INTO TEMPLATE:** Using an existing excel template, the data is read from the static file or database location, and the data is "loaded" into the template; meaning that the data location mapping is static.
4. **PDF GENERATION:** The PDF is created and given a filename based on data from the CSV file and stored to a set directory/folder location.

(If it's not clear, all of this should be automatically done and if the template calls are made/mapped to the same datastore locations - the excel template should be able to just be opened, edited and saved without having to create a custom template for the process.)

**TARGET_OS:** OS-X-10.5, Mac-Office-2011 (mainly due to the templates being created in Mac-Office-2011, though if needed the process could be run on CentOS 5.3 or Window Server 2008)

**QUESTIONS:** Please comment if you have questions, I've generated docs before writing to OpenOffice ODF XML, zipping the file, and printing the PDF (although, can't recall the command-line PDF tool I used.)

Comment: @Remou: Open to any suggestions, links, etc. -- thanks!

Comment: @Remou: I was going to say, Office on the Mac does not have VBA, but Office 2011 does apparently, they put it back in.  So automation may be reasonable.

Comment: @Orbling: +1 Thanks for pointing out Mac Office 2011 supports VBA again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If comments on the original question are correct and Mac does have Visual Basic for Applications embedded, then you can accomplish this all inside of Excel ([tutorial link](http://www.excel-vba.com/)). It can do things like talk to a database, read and write cell values, and I believe shell out to other applications (e.g. PDF generation). Be forewared though, at least one road to hell is paved with Excel VBA.

Greatest roadblock I encountered is no easy way to ensure different users on different computers opening the same workbook (or a copy of that workbook) work.

Instead I would have users upload and download Excel files to and from a web app. You, and ultimately your users, will be *much* happier doing it that way.

Comment: Great, thanks -- once the template is created, it'll live on the server, it's not being distributed to a group of users. I've looked into other options (mainly Jasper Reports) but the user creating the report templates makes them in such a way that they're very non-standard on a row-by-row basis; meaning they're placing static text randomly throughout the report. Figure I'll just let them do whatever they want; it won't be pretty run-time wise, but it'll bring an end to the problem.