# In Excel, using VBA -- how do I import and insert data from a delimited file? (sample code & data)

Tags: excel, vba, import, csv

I've got a sheet setup with the following VBA:

```
Sub PrintPDF()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\<insert_username>\Desktop\macro\Book1.pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False _

Application.Quit

End Sub
```

(which basically opens prints a PDF of the file and closes excel)

Then I've got this in the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Run "PrintPDF"
End Sub
```

(which runs the PrintPDF macro "on load" -- meaning when first thing when the excel file is opened.)

### QUESTION:

So, what I'm missing now to finish out this task is some nice clean code to import a delimited file "on load" and map it to a fixed point in a single sheet.

### Sample Data (with header row):

```
ID<TAB>Name<TAB>Location
1<TAB>John<TAB>US
2<TAB>Mike<TAB>CN
3<TAB>Tom<TAB>CA
```

### Sample Excel Rows (after "on load" insert and mapping to cells):

```
<A1>null<B1>null<C1>null<D1>null
<A2>null<B2>ID<C2>Name<D2>Location
<A3>null<B3>1<C3>John<D3>US
<A4>null<B4>2<C4>Mike<D4>CN
<A5>null<B5>3<C5>Tom<D5>CA
```

(offset the data mapping because I'd like to make sure that I'm able to map the imported data to any where in the excel file as long as the row and column count match in both ends; both ends being the excel file and the delimited data source file; which they will 1-for-1.)

If you have any questions, let me know. The target system is Window 7 (Office 2010) or Mac 10.5 (Office 2011) -- the code above is for Windows, but the only difference I believe would be the filename code, that being: "`C:\Users\<insert_username>\Desktop\macro\Book1.pdf`"

---

### UPDATE:

Here's the code I have so far, anything wrong with it:

```
Sub ImportCSV()
'
' ImportCSV Macro
'

'
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;C:\Users\<insert_username>\Desktop\macro\sample_pipeline_data.txt", Destination:= _
        Range("$B$2"))
        .Name = "sample_pipeline_data"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 437
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Does it work? What's the problem?

Comment: What is the output right now?

Comment: @DJ: There is no problem, it's working -- though 90% of the code above was generated from just recording a macro; which I know is not the best VBA. Just making sure the codes correct, guess I code post it as an answer instead of an update.

Comment: @belisarius: Output is a PDF; which is working. If you wanted to try it, just plug the sample data into a tab delimited file and make sure you update the filename location for: C:\Users\<insert_username>\Desktop\macro\sample_pipeline_data.txt -- also, make sure you excel macro security settings are correct; clearly not making any warranties about the state or condition of the above code; 90% of it was generated by just recording macros via excel itself.

Comment: @blunders I mean, what is the output from the snippet that doesn't work? Perhaps I'm not sure what is your question ...

Comment: @belisarius: Note the the "ImportCSV" is just cut-n-paste before the rendering of the PDF; clearly the "sub..." and "end" are removed from the "ImportCSV" and it's just the commands; if you want me to update the code to be in it's final state, just let me know.

Comment: @belisarius: Everything is working, just don't know VBA and wondering if there's any trash code, or a better way to do any of the above -- and wow, that was a super fast reply... :-) +2 for your two comments.

Comment: @blunders Ahhh ... ok. "If it works ... don't break it" :)

Comment: @belisarius: +1 Ha, true -- and agree, but figure never hurts to ask, and never really trust generated code, that said, I've always found Excel's code from macro's to be very good.

Comment: @blunders Generally macro generated code is nice, showing all relevant parameters. Perhaps everyone use it just because the help is so lame. Anyway, generating recorded macro code is almost always a good template to start with.

Comment: @belisarius: Yep, I agree MS support is so, so -- the Apps and documentation aren't to bad; plus, they've got a huge user base, so there's lots of random stuff about there products via Google. By the way, ran across your post on randomness, long time ago -- it's a very nice post; clear by all the up votes think so too. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA is posted above in the body of my question, but the simple answer is that you can just record a macro using the built in PDF functions to automate this. One thing I would suggest is that you test this marco (or any marco) on the platforms it will be running on. For example, in the VBA code above which was generated using Office 2010 on Windows 7 -- it will not work on Mac 10.5 (Office 2011) without running it in the debugger and deleting a few attributes that Mac's version of office doesn't support (though based on my testing, it appears very likely that they're not supported by the Window's version either, but just don't throw errors.) If you ever have questions about the code/answer -- just comment and I've be happy to provide any additional info.